# Universal FSM in c# to implement any state machine.. and to check any next state on user input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, state, state-machine, fsm

Can it be simpler?  I want it to work universally for any state machine with just changing the main()...transition table any how can I
 get an input from user to choose any state and show next possible
 states as output in a loop.
How can I make it suitable for all machines and how can I get input from user to choose next possible state of the machine?

```cs
    using System; 
    using System.Activities.Statements; 
    using System.Collections; 
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;     
    namespace FSM_PACMAN
     {
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            StateMachine<string> machine = new StateMachine<string>("Sets","Spawned", "SuperPac","Lvlcomplete","Dead","Successfullgameover")
        {
            { "Spawned", "Spawned","Eatcheese" },
            { "Spawned", "Dead", "EatenbyGost" },
            { "Spawned", "Superpac", "EatTablet" },
            { "Spawned", "Lvlcomplete", "Eatlastcheese" },
            { "SuperPac", "SuperPac", "EATcheese" },
            { "SuperPac", "SuperPac", "EATTablet" },
            { "SuperPac", "Spawned", "Timeout" },
            { "SuperPac", "Lvlcomplete", "Eatlastcheese" },
            { "SuperPac", "SuperPac", "EATghost" },
            { "SuperPac", "Dead", "EatenbySpawnedGhost" },
            { "Lvlcomplete", "Spawned", "Lvlleft" },
            { "Lvlcomplete", "Spawned", "NewGame" },
            { "Lvlcomplete", "Successfullgameover", "Nomorelevels" },
            { "Dead", "Spawned", "Lifeleft"},
            { "Dead", "Spawned", "NewGame" },
            { "Successfullgameover", "Spawned", "NewGame" },

        };

            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine(machine);

                Console.WriteLine("current state = " + machine.start);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter State");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                machine.start = input;
                    }
           //Console.WriteLine(StateMachine.Equals());
            //  Console.WriteLine("Nomorelevels -> NewGame " + machine.Accepts(""));
            //  Console.WriteLine("NewGame --> Nomorelevels " + machine.Accepts("NewGameNomorelevels"));
            Console.ReadLine();
            await Task.Delay(100000);
        }
    }

    class StateMachine<T> : IEnumerable<Transition<T>>
    {
        public string start { get; set; }
        HashSet<string> ends = new HashSet<string>();
        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<T, string>> transitions = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<T, string>>();

        public string name { get; set; }

        public StateMachine(string name, string start, params string[] ends)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.start = start;
            this.ends.UnionWith(ends);
        }

        public void Add(string from, string to, T value)
        {
            if (transitions.ContainsKey(from) == false)
                transitions[from] = new Dictionary<T, string>();

            transitions[from][value] = to;
        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            string nodes = string.Join(", ", this.transitions.Keys);
            string values = string.Join(", ", this.transitions[start].Keys);
            string ends = string.Join(", ", this.ends);
            string transitions = string.Join("\n   ", this);

            return $"{name} = (\n{{{nodes}}}, \n{{{values}}}, \nQ,\n Start = {start},\n {{{ends}}})\nQ: {transitions}";
            //return $"{start} = (\n{{{nodes}}}, \n{{{values}}}, \nQ,\n Start = {start},\n {{{ends}}})\nQ: {transitions}";

        }

        public IEnumerator<Transition<T>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return transitions.SelectMany(
                node => node.Value.Select(to => new Transition<T>(node.Key, to.Value, to.Key))).GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

       /* public bool Accepts(IEnumerable<T> @string)
        {
            string state = start;

            foreach (T value in @string)
                state = transitions[state][value];

            return ends.Contains(state);
        }
        */

    }

class Transition<T>
    {
        public string From { get; }
        public string To { get; }
        public T Value { get; }

        public Transition(string from, string to, T value)
        {
            From = from;
            To = to;
            Value = value;
        }

        public override string ToString() => $"q({From}, {Value}) = {To}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest FSM implements a `State Next(Event e)` method, and yours doesn't do that. You should not expect every consumer to iterate through all transitions to find the next state.

States should be value types, like Enums, not reference types like Strings, and you should implement transition tables like `Dictionary<ValueTuple<State current, Event transition>, State result>`, not as a `Dictionary<State current, <Dictionary<Event transition, State result>>` which will require a double lookup.

Finite State machines are a fundamental concept in computer science, you should study some theory and existing implementations.

Comment: im new with state machines and transition table.. can u refer me to some source of universal state machine and in simpler code.